# How big should the admin_user password column be?

Tags: login, password

I have been having an issue where the `self::HASH_SALT_LENGTH` constant is `32` in `/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php`.

So the hashed password is: 65 characters long.

Yet in the database that column is set as `varchar(40)` so it is always failing.

How big should that column be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the admin password column is 100 characters

[image: Admin password column length]